# How to migrate Database from Room Native to Flutter Database?

Tags: android, flutter, android-room, flutter-floor

Is there any way to migrate native app which have Room database to Flutter App with own database without loss the existing data? I have large number of user so i can't export the database and import into app directory.

Comment: hi, have you got your solution? is it possible?